# Matayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106297/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stam mishna's pesak on the ratio to nullify Orlah- 200:1

Comment: ...and Klai haKerem

Answer (score 3):

Total obligation on a kesubah for a besulah- 100 zuz + 100 zuz

Answer (score 3):

The amount of she-goats and ewes (each) that Yaakov sent Esav to find favor.

וַיָּלֶן שָׁם בַּלַּיְלָה הַהוּא וַיִּקַּח מִן-הַבָּא בְיָדוֹ מִנְחָה לְעֵשָׂו אָחִיו.   עִזִּים מָאתַיִם

Answer (score 3):

רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר אוֹמֵר: מִנַּיִן שֶׁכָּל מַכָּה וּמַכָּה שֶׁהֵבִיא הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עַל הַמִּצְרִים בְּמִצְרַיִם הָיְתָה שֶׁל אַרְבַּע מַכּוֹת? שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: יְשַׁלַּח בָּם חֲרוֹן אַפּוֹ, עֶבְרָה וָזַעַם וְצָרָה, מִשְׁלַחַת מַלְאֲכֵי רָעִים. עֶבְרָה - אַחַת, וָזַעַם - שְׁתַּיִם, וְצָרָה - שָׁלשׁ, מִשְׁלַחַת מַלְאֲכֵי רָעִים - אַרְבַּע. אֱמוֹר מֵעַתָּה: בְּמִצְרַיִם לָקוּ אַרְבָּעִים מַכּוֹת וְעַל הַיָּם לָקוּ **מָאתַיִם** מַכּוֹת

Thus you must now say that in Egypt they were struck by forty plagues, and at the sea they were stricken by two hundred plagues.

Answer (score 2):

[Supposedly](http://www.freewebs.com/hebrewlang/), a shibboleth by which to recognize Jerusalemites is that they pronounce the word for 200 as "maatayim" (instead of standard Israeli Hebrew "matayim").

Answer (score 1):

שמואל א: יח. כז.
ויקם דוד וילך הוא ואנשיו ויך בפלשתים **מאתים** איש ויבא דוד את ערלתיהם וימלאום למלך להתחתן במלך ויתן לו שאול את מיכל בתו לאשה

Answer (score 1):

שמואל ב: יד. כו.
ובגלחו את ראשו והיה מקץ ימים לימים אשר יגלח כי כבד עליו וגלחו ושקל את שער ראשו **מאתים** שקלים באבן המלך

Answer (score 0):

ויחי שרוג אחרי הולידו את נחור **מאתים** שנה ויולד בנים ובנות

Answer (score 0):

שמואל א: כה. יח.
ותמהר אבוגיל ותקח **מאתים** לחם ושנים נבלי יין וחמש צאן עשוות וחמש סאים קלי ומאה צמקים ומאתים דבלים ותשם על החמרים

Answer (score 0):

שמואל ב: טו. יא.
ואת אבשלום הלכו **מאתים** איש מירושלם קראים והלכים לתמם ולא ידעו כל דבר

Answer (score 0):

דברי הימים א: טו. ח.
לבני אליצפן שמעיה השר ואחיו **מאתים**

Answer (score 0):

דברי הימים ב: ט. טו.
ויעש המלך שלמה **מאתים** צנה זהב שחוט שש מאות זהב שחוט יעלה על הצנה האחת

Answer (score 0):

דברי הימים ב: יז. טז.
ועל ידו עמסיה בן זכרי המתנדב ליהוה ועמו **מאתים** אלף גבור חיל

Answer (score 0):

דברי הימים ב: כט. לב.
ויהי מספר העלה אשר הביאו הקהל בקר שבעים אילים מאה כבשים **מאתים** לעלה ליהוה כל אלה

Answer (score 0):

Two hundred are the Issacharites who led the Sanhedrin (chron I 12:32, gen rabbah 98:17).